# How to recognize the language of text in an image from a Java program for Android using Google's ML Kit?

Tags: java, android, computer-vision, google-mlkit

I want to recognize text from different languages across globe in any image and translate to English.
Google's ML KIT for vision supports 5 different Text recognizers for the 5 scripts: Latin, Devanagari, Chinese, Japanese and Korean.
Do I need to use each of the text recognizers to check if the language in the image can be recognized by that Text recognizer?
Is there a shorter way to detect the language of the text in an image?